# Why does this HTML code fail to display color fields?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The following HTML (plus JavaScript plus CSS style sheet) is supposed to display a text with all "a"s replaced by yellow color fields. I know it's a very n00b'y question, but I can't figure out why it fails to do this task.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<style>
span {
    display: inline-block;
}
span.a {background-color: yellow
}
</style>

<script>
var lipsum = document.getElementsByTagName("div")

[0].innerHTML;

lipsum = lipsum.replace( /a/gi, "###a###" );


lipsum = lipsum.replace( /###a###/gi, "<span 

class='a'>&ensp;</span>" );


document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML = 

lipsum;
</script>


</head>

<body>

<div>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci velit</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script is running before the HTML div is even loaded. You need to place your code either in a document ready event handler, or place it below the element. Pages are run in order, so you can't run JS on an element before it's reached because it doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

In the css , add ( ; ) after the background color

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me?

Try to run the code below. Your code seems to work?

```js
var lipsum = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML;

lipsum = lipsum.replace(/a/gi, "###a###");


lipsum = lipsum.replace(/###a###/gi, "<span class='a'>&ensp;</span>");


document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML = lipsum;
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
span.a {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<div>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci velit</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add **onload** event to the **body** to trigger the script.
Since the script was running even when your document has not ben rendered yet.

```
<body onload="init()">
    <div>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci velit</div>
</body>

<script>
    function init() {
        var lipsum = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML;

        lipsum = lipsum.replace( /a/gi, "###a###" );

        lipsum = lipsum.replace( /###a###/gi, "<span class='a'>&ensp;</span>" );

        document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML = lipsum;
    }
</script>
```